# how do to get dropdown value using Uipath?

Tags: rpa, uipath

I need to select the **state** value one by one all from the dropdown using UiPath.

[image]

Comment: Is this not trivial by reading the manual / help file and examples?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Studio
2. Click [image: Recorder]
3. Record the whole clicks on the dropdown
4. Click Save

Answer (score 1):

Use the below activity in uipath - Select Item

https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/select-item

Answer (score 0):

Go to Activities and use the 'Select Item' Activity.
UiPath.UiAutomation.Activities is standard so no need to get an additional Nuget Package downloaded.

Then just Select your Element and it should display the possible options to select.
Then you can replace the selections with a variable that you might want to select.